# Backticks in snippets for Emacs

Tags: emacs, markdown, code-snippets, backticks, yasnippet

I am trying to create a code block snippet for Markdown in Emacs.

I tried to create a snippet like so:

````
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: code-block
# key: cb
# ---

```${1:r}
${2:code}
```
````

but when I tried to save, it threw an error saying `wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

How can I get this snippet to work?

Comment: A pair of surrounding backticks within a snippet are a special way of telling yasnippet to evaluate the code in between the backticks.  I would probably try escaping them with one or more backslashes and see if that has the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to escape the backticks with a backslash.

From [the documentation](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#outline-container-sec-3-1):

> ### Plain Text
>
> Arbitrary text can be included as the content of a template. They are usually interpreted as plain text, except `$` and `` ` ``. You need to use `\` to escape them: `\$` and `` \` `` . The `\` itself may also needed to be escaped as `\\` sometimes.